# google-signin don't return user info

Tags: polymer, web-component, google-signin, google-web-component

I am using [google-signin](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin) element from Google Web Components, but I don't know how to return user info.

```
<google-signin
      client-id="{{my-id}}" scopes="email profile"
      signed-in="{{signedIn}}"></google-signin>
```

I tried to write some JS function but it didn't work.

```
function (signedIn) {
       var profile = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
       console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
       console.log('Image: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  }
```

Excuse me if this is stupid questions, but I am not good at web developing.
Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From polymer documentation:

> The **google-signin-success** event is triggered when a user successfully
>   authenticates and **google-signin-failure** is triggered when this is not
>   the case. Both events will also provide the data returned by the
>   Google client authentication process. You can also use **isAuthorized**
>   attribute to observe authentication state.
>
> Additional events, such as **google-signout-attempted** and
>   **google-signed-out** are triggered when the user attempts to sign-out and
>   successfully signs out.
>
> The **google-signin-necessary** event is fired when scopes requested via
>   google-signin-aware elements require additional user permissions.

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin

```
<google-signin ... id="myLoginIn"></google-signin>
<script>
  var t = document.querySelector('#t');

  t.addEventListener('google-signin-success', function(data) {
    ...
  });
</script>
```

Or you can use:

```
<google-signin client-id="{{my-id}}" scopes="email profile" signed-in="{{signedIn}}"></google-signin>

<google-signin-aware
        scopes="{{scope}}"
        signed-in="{{signedIn}}"
        is-authorized="{{isAuthorized}}"
        need-additional-auth="{{needAdditionalAuth}}"
        on-google-signin-aware-success="handleSignIn"
        on-google-signin-aware-signed-out="handleSignOut"></google-signin-aware>
```

And then you can get username name like that:

```
var aware = document.querySelector('#awareness');
aware.handleSignIn = function(response) {
      console.log('[Aware] Signin Response', response);
      var userName = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile().getName();
};
```

Here you can find the full demo: https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-signin/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: Thanks sensor, great explanation. I was successful in getting google-signin-aware working and functioning when I run it in the browser, but when I run it on my device, I get the following in handleSignIn: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentUser' of null".  This happens when I run it through Android Studio or when I generate a signed apk after changing my client id to the Android one. Any help is appreciated.